# reset a time field time with a update query

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a big db on mysql that contains more than 3 milion records.

I have a "time" (hh:mm:ss) field called arrival_time. 
That time may could be wrong like 24:00:00 (thats in fact  indicate 00:00:00) or again 25:11:00 (--> 1:11:00) etc..
I'd like to perform something like

```
UPDATE 'table' SET arrival_time=(arrival_time_ADJUSTED) WHERE arrival_time>"23:59:59";
```

could be the right and faster approach? And how can I tell to SQL to give the right value to arrival_time?
thanks in adavance.

Comment: Ideally this kind of validations should be handled via the application front-end during the entry itself.

Comment: its an update on an old data set...we needs to update it :(

Comment: Is the field type "time"?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your table definition.

Comment: this is a fake table...no primary key... I've just put it on a table from a txt to try to manipulate it, the arrival_time field is defined as "time"

Comment: can you provide us with your table columns, and your html form (if you have one) ?

Comment: I just want to note that @Nimesh's comment is an opinion that many people would disagree with.  Databases offer robust solutions for validating data integrity and (in my opinion) these capabilities *should* often be in the database and not the application.

Comment: no forms or validation, the collection is a static text file that's need to be manually updated. With a `select [...] WHERE arrival_tima>"23:59:59" `I can find all the rows thats need to be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET arrival_time = TIMEDIFF(arrival_time, '24:00:00')
WHERE arrival_time > '23:59:59';
```

This is assuming, the maximum value is arrival time is 47:59:59. If you have higher records, then repeat the query again till all records are corrected

Comment: very good I'll try asap, I was in the same direction...I make some trys with STR_TO_DATE()